# How to get data from jQuery.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is that i wanna use post data outside it's function, example:

```
$(function() {
  var s = 'something ';
  $.post('ajax.php', {option: 'test'}, function(data) {
    s += data; // data: 'hello world';
  });
  alert(s); // output: 'something ';
});
```

my expected result is 'something hello world'.
how can i deal with this? 
Thanks

Comment: what you need is to make an ajax call in this case

Comment: are you sure you ajax.php page is working correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.ajax` with `async:false`, I assume the data is coming as `content-type:json/application` e.g.

```
var s = 'something ';
$.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({option: 'test'}),
      dataType: "json",
      async:false,
      success: function(msg){
         s += msg.data;//msg={data: "hello world"}
      }
   }
);
alert(s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Shouldn't that be:

```
   $(function() {
       var s = 'something ';
       $.post('ajax.php', {option: 'test'}, function(data) {
         s += data; // data: 'hello world';
        alert(s); // output: 'something ';
       });
    });
```

Obviously, the data will be available in `s` only after the ajax call has been completed (as Alex pointed out), but after that it will be persistent...

Answer (score 3):

```
var s = 'something ';

$.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: ({option: 'test'}),
      async:false,
      success: function(data){
         s += data;
      }
   }
);

 alert(s);
```

you need to synchronize the request by  `async:false,`

Comment: Why `async: false`? How is it relevant to this question? OP is not sending muliple ajax request !!!

Comment: @Starx: What does "multiple ajax request" have to do with asynchronous versus synchronous AJAX calls? OP seems to want their AJAX call to behave like a normal function call, `async:false` is one way to do that.

Comment: @mu is too short,  Are you trying to say Synchronous ajax request and Asynchronous ajax request doesn't have anything to do with multiple ajax requests? I thought the term Asynchronous and Synchronous arose because of sending mulitple requests.

Comment: @littletipz: THANK for ur answers it is helpful. i have done it with ur answer ^_^ ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error; there should be a `)` at the end of the `post()` callback.

In addition, when that `alert()` is called, the XHR has not finished yet and assigned the new info to that variable. You would need to place it in the callback of `post()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write the data to any number of html elements and have it available outside of the function.  You could use a global variable.  You could store in session.  Many answers here.  Do I understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

You code should be working. Unless the `ajax.php` is not echoing "Hello World" at the end. Please make sure of it and try to post the results. Errors or output, whatever you can feed us.